# Javascript Window.Onload Function Chaining

Tags: javascript, function, onload, method-chaining

Just for the sake of experimentation, I've been trying to determine different ways to non-destructively chain `window.onload` functions in a web browser. This is the idea of what I have so far:

```
var load = window.onload;
var newFunction = function(){
    alert("ha!");
}
window.onload = function(){
    load();
    newFunction();
}
```

The problem I see with this is that every time you chain a function, it adds another level of function calls to the stack. Is there a better way to go about this that doesn't add unnecessary depth to the call stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be it will be better to use addEventListener/attachEvent?

[Advanced event registration models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) how they handle that.

From the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn):

> You can have as many $(document).ready events on your page as you like. The functions are then executed in the order they were added.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use the "good enough" addEvent:

```
var addEvent = function( obj, type, fn ) {
        if (obj.addEventListener)
                obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        else if (obj.attachEvent) 
                obj.attachEvent('on' + type, function() { return fn.apply(obj, new Array(window.event));});
}
```

From: http://www.ilfilosofo.com/blog/2008/04/14/addevent-preserving-this/